# rewrite/redirect specific word from url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have couple of urls which is generated by wordpress/php

- http://mydomain.com/news-2/newsarticle
- http://mydomain.com/products/category-2
- http://mydomain.com/products/category/products-2

how can I rewrite/redirect any url with **-2** to the one without? The result should be

- http://mydomain.com/news/newsarticle
- http://mydomain.com/products/category
- http://mydomain.com/products/category/products

This is what I have so far

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need that there as a unique identifier?

Comment: I may have done what I wanted to do in a bit of a convoluted way...? I created a custom post post type so I can pull content to the homepage but actual links going to default pages... I am new to WP backend dev

Answer (score 2):

Add this to you htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-2(.*)$ /$1$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```